# Como atualizar uma resposta e tornar claro que/onde houve atualização?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, edição, respostas

Estou perguntando isso porque vi em uma resposta em [determinada revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/257281/2) o seguinte trecho de texto:

> Também tem alteração no código abaixo

Essa frase no meu ver só faz sentido dado o contexto da revisão anterior e para chamar a atenção de alguém para um determinado trecho. Simplesmente não vejo essa frase se sustentando como parte do texto final de um conhecimento consolidado.

Outros exemplos (mais estáveis quanto ao que toca a parte de conhecimento consolidado) que vi foi o AR colocar seções com **Update** (inclusive eu mesmo fiz isso algumas vezes). Muitas vezes é apenas uma edição sem marca significante no formato.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Devemos notificar e tornar claro onde houve essas mudanças?
- Como devemos notificar o AP/parte interessado de trechos alterados? Devemos por isso literalmente no texto da resposta? Ou apenas marcar a pessoa em um comentário descrevendo a mudança?
- Marcas de atualização de resposta são boas? São más? Podem ser uma ou outra dependendo de circunstância?
- Ao ver casos semelhantes, e em que essas marcas não são mais úteis/são ruídos ruins no texto, devemos limpar esses ruídos? Notificar o AR?

Comment: Sobre o caso específico que você linkou, eu li de outra maneira. Como a revisão incluiu o conteúdo de um outro arquivo, o "também" da frase se refere a esse outro arquivo

Comment: @bfavaretto então neste caso específico deve ter sido só um estranhamento da minha parte, talvez por não ter curtido o estilo do AR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Devemos notificar e tornar claro onde houve essas mudanças?

Eu diria que não. Não é que seja proibido, mas lembre-se da nossa filosofia que as respostas são para todo mundo e devem durar. Notificações de mudança ficam como conversa com o interessado e deixa de fazer sentido logo depois que ela é feita.

> Como devemos notificar o AP/parte interessado de trechos alterados? Devemos por isso literalmente no texto da resposta? Ou apenas marcar a pessoa em um comentário descrevendo a mudança?

Claramente o segundo, o comentário é para isto.

> Marcas de atualização de resposta são boas? São más? Podem ser uma ou outra dependendo de circunstância?

De forma geral são más por ferir nossa filosofia, mas para tudo pode existir exceção.

> Ao ver casos semelhantes, e em que essas marcas não são mais úteis/são ruídos ruins no texto, devemos limpar esses ruídos? Notificar o AR?

Acredito que sim, ambos. Mas não é obrigatório, nada é.